Which one is invalid relationship from the uml diagram shown below?
According to me correct choice is A because aggregation and composition relations can't coexist within the same class.
However, option C also seems plausible, creating some  confusion for me.
Option b and d are valid according to me. So the confusion is between a and c.


Why have you deleted the picture ? It's difficult for other readers to understand without it. Could you restore it, because it's a quite interesting puzzle, we find :-)

@Christophe Geert did it for you. And you can do that as well...

Option D is perfectly valid. It models a typical hierarchical or a lattice structure.
Option B is perfectly valid. It belongs to  a typical variant of the composite pattern.
Option A is perfectly valid. A same occurrence cannot be member of two compositions. But composition and aggregation are not incompatible.
Option C needs a closer look:

At first sight the two relationships are not incompatible.
I then thought it might be related to the circular dependency of a an abstraction on its realization.  However, as Jim and Geert rightly pointed out, nothing forbids this in the UML standard.  Furthermore, I managed to successfully compile in several implementation language exactly this situation.
In the end, it appears that in UML, option C is not wrong either.  Indeed, UML allows a realization between two classifiers,  which then means that the one realises   the specifications of the other. Nothing forbids to have this between two classes in addition to the composition in any of the direction.
However such relationship is really not common between classes in real life (uml does not specify what it means in practice).  Realization is in general used for components or interfaces.  In both cases, an adornment would be missing: either the keyword «component» (or the corresponding icon) or the keyword «interface». This is the only reason why option C would look weird although not being wrong.

So in conclusion, the question itself is misleading and probably based on incomplete knowledge of UML.

I don’t see anything wrong with answer C. It’s perfectly valid for an interface to compose a realization of its interface. E.g., it might be a variant of the strategy pattern.

I agree with @JimL. For a regular Realization this is not invalid. If an InterfaceRealization was meant, than F should have been an interface, and not a class. I'm guessing that is what the quiz author actually meant.

@JimL. Indeed, I revise my position as I found no constraint forbidding this situation in the UML specs.

@GeertBellekens I agree and revised my answer.  Indeed, the claimed wrongness is probabley related to the missing «interface», but as you rightly pointed out,  noting prevents a general realization between two classes, and the standard is defined quite flexibly in this regard (interestingly,  substitution is also a specialization of the general realization, although it's notation deviates from the general realization).

I’m suspicious of having a composition and an aggregation, but can’t think of anything authoritative.

This is the best UML puzzle I’ve seen in a long time!

@JimL. Indeed,  this was a good candidate,  but having had some heated discussions on that, I know that the constraints are on the object and not the class:  "Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in at most one composite object at a time".  The only other constraint is that the upper bound on composition side is at most 1, and if the other end is not a shared or composite aggregation (p.200)
